# BST with 2d array as key in node structure instead of int

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, binary-search-tree

In binary search tree we have the node strucure as

```
class Node
{
    public:
    int key;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

};
```

So while creating a node we do

```
Node* createNode(int key)
{
    Node *node=new Node();
    node->key=key;
    node->left=NULL;
    node->right=NULL;

    return node;
}
```

Now i want key ad 2d matrix instead of integer key. Something like this

```
class Node
{
    public:
    char matrix[3][3];
    Node *left;
    Node *right;


};
```

How to create node now?

```
Node* createNode(char key[3][3])
{
    Node *node=new Node();
    node->matrix=key;     //This line
    return node;
}
```

Comment: That isn't valid java code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ it is equally simple:

```
vector<vector<double> > matrix;
vector<double> &row = matrix[i];
```

In C that would be

```
double *row = Matrix[i];
```

Note that the C way works in C++ as well, but you should prefer containers to plain pointers whenever you can.

Comment: Should be noted that these two versions to totally different things.

Comment: @CrazyEddie That should be entirely clear from the reference to a different programming language (C vs. C++).

Comment: Goes way beyond that.  The C++ version creates a copy of the row.  The C version points at it.  This is a very significant difference that has nothing to do with being different languages.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Oh, I did not realize that's what you meant. I modified the answer so that C++ does not perform a copy.

Answer (score 0):

To get a row, it's simple, like @dasblinkenlight said. However, to get a column, it's much more involved. Assuming that you know the number of rows in the matrix, you can do the following:

```
int *copyColumn(int **matrix, int column, int rows)
{
    int *data = new int[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
         data[i] = matrix[i][column];

    return data;
}
```

Just remember to `delete` data when you are done with it!